# Mediawiki: import, render and use correctly Infobox template

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I'd like to have some info boxes in my pages.

So that. I've installed Scribunto extension (downloaded, copied in the extension folder, changed local settings, added permission to lua standalone bins).

Then I've been in a wiki that has an info box like the one I'd like to have, exported the pages with template checkbox checked and imported into my wiki.

Now, if I go to `mywiki/Template:Infobox` I see something that it seems not well rendered to me. It is the code of info box, I attach a screenshot.

What is happening?

This is my setting:

- MediaWiki    1.22.5
- PHP  5.3.3-7+squeeze18 (apache2handler)
- MySQL    5.1.73-1
- Lua  5.1.5

[image]

Comment: I think you need to enable [the `ParserFunctions` extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`#if`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23if) is part of [the `ParserFunctions` extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions), so you need to enable that.